# How to run a program if another program is running c# or .bat

Tags: c#, batch-file, discord

So I have a discord server and everytime i launch discord I have to launch my music bot which is a .bat file. Is there any way that I can make a program that start when windows does and checks every 10 seconds if discord is open and if it is it runs the music bot. This shouldn't take a lot of processing power or instead of every 10 seconds make it that when i run discord.exe it runs the musicbot.
Thank You

Comment: Place your program in the startup windows folder, you can get here by opening RUN and type shell:startup. Than the startup folder will open.

Comment: yeah i guess that works thanks

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a .bat program that launches your bot and discard at the same time and set the icon of the program to Discords "app.ico".

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Discord\app-0.0.298"
start Discord.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\batch"
start myBot.bat
exit
```